# Do we need Prometheus Metrics in Azure Monitor?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-monitor

[Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-prometheus-integration) talks about how Azure Monitor can be used to scrape Prometheus Metrics. The scope of this question is limited to K8 cluster monitoring (not workload/apps deployed on it). Based on my understanding, even Prometheus uses agents(also called exporters) to publish the metrics exposed by K8 API server (typically /metrics endpoint) and then Prometheus scrapes metrics through these endpoints.

Azure Monitor for containers also does same thing (collecting from API server) and even more. It provides pretty exhaustive [list of metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-metrics).

My question is: Unless I'm looking at app/workload integration (or Prometheus format) am I missing anything iof I use just Azure Monitor for containers and not really scrape Prometheus metrics of my AKS cluster/nodes/pods/api server etc.?

Answer (score 0):

No, is perfectly fine to collect only the cluster metrics if you need them.

In the "prometheus-data-collection-settings" just leave the monitor_kubernetes_pods to false.

```
prometheus-data-collection-settings: |- 
[prometheus_data_collection_settings.cluster] 
interval = "1m"
kubernetes_services = ["http://my-service-dns.my-namespace:9102/metrics"]
monitor_kubernetes_pods = false
```

Just keep in mind all this discussion makes sense only if you care about getting your metrics using the Prometheus endpoints; in general, AKS emits metrics already on its own you can check in Azure Monitor.